# How to get AppID for fan page?

Tags: facebook

All my old fan pages appear in Apps on FB dev site. How to force a newly created fan page to appear there to get AppID and App Secret?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Page isn't an application. If you create new application, you'll get page and new appid with appsecret.

Comment: I created fan pages long time ago and they all appear in apps list.

Comment: Probably not. You have created applications which created fan pages

Comment: I've created that pages longer time ago. Probably it changed. The problem is, that I don't want the fan page to appear as "fan page of app" but give it proper categories (e.g. sport club)

Comment: So just create one page and one application

Comment: this is exactely what I wanted to avoid. for old pages I have automatically created App ID/API Key, there must be a way :)

Comment: here's the old page:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/BAFKA/47095357887
and here's the relevant app to the page I did not create:
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=109163328255

Comment: @ifaour read our comments, I thought it too, but he said "no"

Comment: thanks guys, but to make it clear:
my old pages appear all in apps list (like automaticaly created app for each page with appid/app key, secret
maybe it's an old feature (fb does not create apps automatically anymore?) or there are some uknown conditions (published page, at least 1 like, it may take "several minutes/days")
do you have similar experiences? did fb created app automaticaly for a fan page?

Comment: hmm so you guys (@genesisφ & @Peter) agreed on calling the *Application Profile Page* as *Application Fan Page*. Fair enough :)

Comment: @PeterSorger if you are sure that these *pages* shouldn't be under the Dev dashboard, then I prefer you contact Facebook

Comment: @iafour i would like to achieve the opposite :) to have app for the page

Comment: @PeterSorger: that'S the same